Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '26-09-2021' for function str_to_date
command:
update h1b_data set RECEIVED_DATE = str_to_date(RECEIVED_DATE, "%d%m%Y");

h1b_data is table name and RECEIVED_DATE is column name.
trying to update the date-format according to the MySQL's original format.
but getting

Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '26-09-2021' for function str_to_date


What type is RECEIVED_DATE? Shouldn't it be a DATE type column?

If RECEIVED_DATE is a DATE field, then it is not a string, so the function will not work. And Date values should never be stored a strings, only as Date or DateTime types.

data type of RECEIVED_DATE is varchar(255) while loading the data-file from source to MySQL server.
first I am updating the value of column then will change it's data type

if there are dashes in the data you need to include them in the format..

@AnushriD. Why do you not save the date in a DATE type column when you retrieve the data from the source?

alright ..
the issue was here itself..
their is dash present in between date-month-year in the column data
which I forgot to include in command.
now it's running by following command-->
update h1b_data set RECEIVED_DATE =  str_to_date(RECEIVED_DATE, "%d-%m-%Y");

You get this error message because the input string '26-09-2021' does not match the expected format "%d%m%Y". If you use this format then the value should be '26092021'. Either change the input to '26092021' so it matches the format "%d%m%Y" or change the format to "%d-%m-%Y" so it matches the input string '26-09-2021'.

if your column data is having dash or hyphen or slash in between date,month and year then include it in the command without fail, for ex. 2021-09-26
solution command-->
update h1b_data set RECEIVED_DATE =  str_to_date(RECEIVED_DATE, "%d-%m-%Y");

repeating an answer is not going to help anyone.

Kindly check other's answer and then post your opinion.
